# Paster cannot stop daemon

Tags: python, command-line, ssh, pylons, paster

I'm using the following command in my pylons app in an attempt to stop the daemon on the server:

```
paster serve --daemon dev.ini stop
```

This is the error I get:

```
No PID file exists in paster.pid
Could not stop daemon; aborting
```

Wondering how I can stop this daemon so I can reload dev.ini.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kill the process.

Comment: No, honestly. kill [processnumber] That's what you do.

Comment: Surely not! I have the same problem, and I am trying to automate it... I'm going to ask a more detailed question to see if I can get to the root cause.

Comment: I've asked more detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463388/paster-daemon-wont-shut-down-because-cant-read-own-pid-file